# Set the default text color for "Value History" and "Quick Look" for Playground on XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

I have been trying to find a way to set the default text color for "**Value History**" and "**Quick Look**" for Playground on XCode. But, I couldn't find any settings for that.

The below screen shot shows both the text color and also the background color for "**Value History**" and "**Quick Look**" are white. I couldn't see the text without highlighting it.

[image]

How do I change the text color to black?

Comment: I guess it's using "plain text" color setting from your current theme.

Comment: I just tried that. Set a different color on "plain text" only changes the color for the variable name and other operators like aColor, =, .blueColor() from the screen shot above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has already fixed in Xcode6-Beta3, check it out!

Comment: You are right. It has been fixed on Xcode6-Beta3. Thanks for letting me know. ;)